# Extracting SpatialPolygonsDataFrame attributes into a dataframe in R. Assigning new vars based on other polygon in R

Tags: raster, r, polygon, attribute-table, sp

Here you can see a group of small and large polygons. Small polygons are cropped as I am only interested in their properties, such as size inside the large polygons. I have two furhter objectives where I need help:

1 - Assign new attribute `field_id` to individual polygons in `Pol_small`. The new attribute field will have either `1` or `2` and this will represent within which `Pol_large` is the individual `Pol_small` located. In other words, all the polygons on the left (`Pol1, Pol2, Pol3, Pol4`) will have `1` in the new attribute column, and four polygons on the right (`Pol5, Pol6, Pol7, Pol8`) will have `2`.

2 - Extract information about `Pol_small_crop` into a `dataframe`. Each row would represent each individual polygon within `Pol_small_crop` so a total of 8 rows. I am interested in the area [in sq km] of the cropped polygons (shown in red), and migrating all the other attributes, such as created `field_id` and others. In this example, te only attributes remaining will be `ID`.

[The same question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60119790/edit) is posted on SO, I just realised GIS StackExchange is a more appropriate place for it.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)

create_poly <- function(coordin,id_number){
  coordinates = matrix(c(coordin[1], coordin[3],
                    coordin[1], coordin[4],
                    coordin[2], coordin[4],
                    coordin[2], coordin[3],
                    coordin[1], coordin[3]), 
                  ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)


  P_1 = Polygon(coordinates)
  Ps_1 = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(P_1), ID = id_number)), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))
  ID_1 <- sapply(slot(Ps_1, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID"))
  df <- data.frame(rep(0, length(ID_1)), row.names=ID_1)
  Ps1_df <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(Ps_1, df)
  Ps1_df
}

# Create shapefile with polygon boundaries of interest:
Pol_large1 <- create_poly(c(80,100,20,40),1)
Pol_large2 <- create_poly(c(120,140,30,50),1)

# Join the polygons into one layer:
Pol_large <- do.call(rbind, list(Pol_large1, Pol_large2))

# Create smaller polygons:
Pol2 <- create_poly(c(79,83,19,30),2)
Pol3 <- create_poly(c(90,92,25,30),3)
Pol4 <- create_poly(c(90,95,33,37),4)
Pol5 <- create_poly(c(98,110,21,24),5)

Pol6 <- create_poly(c(119,123,29,35),6)
Pol7 <- create_poly(c(130,131,33,40),7)
Pol8 <- create_poly(c(130,137,45,47),8)
Pol9 <- create_poly(c(116,125,45,49),9)

# Join the polygons into one layer:
Pol_small <- do.call(rbind,list(Pol2, Pol3, Pol4, Pol5,
                                Pol6, Pol7, Pol8, Pol9))

plot(Pol_large, axes = TRUE)
plot(Pol_small, add=TRUE)

# Crop out polygons
Pol_small_crop <- crop(Pol_large,Pol_small)
plot(Pol_small_crop, border = "red", add=TRUE)
```

[image]